# ASYNC - Pandas read_sql and asyncio?

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to solve this following problem. I am trying to come up with a solution using pandas.read_sql and asyncio. I want to migrate table records from 1 database to another database.

I want to do the following:

```
table 1
.
.
.
table n
```

I have the function:

```
def extract(table):
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df = pd.concat(
              [chunk for chunk in
                  pd.read_sql(sql,
                              con=CONNECTION,
                              chunksize=10**5)]
                    )
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        return df
```

I want to run these in parallel and not one by one.

```
extract(table1)
extract(table2)
.
.
extract(tablen)
```

Comment: Is asyncio a hard requirement? Have you considered threads or multiprocessing?

Comment: yeah, but maybe i could get some idea using threads or multiprocessing. but ive heard that theres a lot of problems that can occur using those methods.

Comment: Even if asyncio were a hard requirement, an asyncio-based solution would still use threads under the hood to run `DataFrame.read_sql` in parallel. With that in mind, it is better to use `concurrent.futures`, which provides excellent tools for parallelizing code.

Comment: So what is the solution? I have encountered a similar case. @user4815162342

Comment: @Algo The accepted answer shows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asyncio is about organizing non-blocking code into callbacks and coroutines. Running CPU-intensive code in parallel is a use case for threads:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    frames = list(executor.map(extract, all_tables))
```

Whether this will actually run faster than sequential code depends on whether `pd.read_sql` releases the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: is there any way to check or release it in python code? something like: while fetching: release GIL for other function to run in parallel?

Comment: another question: can u manage the result immediately on a ThreadPoolExecutor or do you need to wait untill all the extract(tab1...tabn) are finished?

Comment: @Maki You can't release the GIL in Python, but C extensions can do it when safe. (Panda's authors are [aware](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#releasing-the-gil) of this.) If you need to manage results as they arrive, look into executor's [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method. It returns a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) which you can manage in various ways, including registering a callback to be executed when the result is ready.

Comment: @Maki Also see [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed), an iterator which accepts a bunch of futures and yields them as they finish.

Comment: You can use ProcessPoolExecutor as drop-in replacement for multiprocessing. But you may get issues with passing the connection object to the daughter process, in this case you need to open a new one there.