# Read from database using pd.read_sql and asyncio

Tags: python, pandas, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have three tables which each takes around 1 minute to query from (i.e total of 3 min) like this

```py
from my_utils import get_engine
import pandas as pd

def main():
   con1 = get_engine("table1")
   con2 = get_engine("table2")
   con3 = get_engine("table3")

   df1 = pd.read_sql(query1,con=con1)
   df2 = pd.read_sql(query2,con=con2)
   df3 = pd.read_sql(query3,con=con3)

main()
```

which yields to the sky to be "asynchronized".

I have thus tried the following (I'm rather new to using `asyncio`)

```py
.
.
import asyncio

async def get_df1(query1):
   df1 = pd.read_sql(query1,con=con1)
   return df1

async def get_df2(query2):
   df2 = pd.read_sql(query2,con=con2)
   return df2

async def get_df3(query3):
   df3 = pd.read_sql(query3,con=con3)
   return df3

async def main():

 df1,df2,df3 = await asyncio.gather(get_df1(),get_df2(),get_df3())

asyncio.run(main())
```

It runs, but it takes the exact same time, as the sync-run.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You may want to look at this answer as well if the goal is just to execute queries in parallel and you are not wedded to asyncio coroutines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426533/async-pandas-read-sql-and-asyncio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching between coroutines only occurs at an `await` statement, and since there are no `await`s in your `get_df` functions your three queries will only ever be executed sequentially. Since `pd.read_sql` is not natively async, you'll have to wrap it with an executor to make an async version:

```
async def read_sql_async(stmt, con):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, pd.read_sql, stmt, con)
```

You'll then be able to run `read_sql` as an awaitable:

```
df1 = await read_sql_async(query1, con=con1)
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick! ALthough one of my queries is stalling (I don't if theres many requests to the DB atm) - but is there some issue in createing a loop in each function, i.e if you copy your example 10 times thus creating the loop in each function?

Comment: You can use a loop to set up each future before executing them all with `gather` (if that's what you mean?) e.g. if you have lists of queries and connections you could do `results = await asyncio.gather(*(read_sql_async(query, con) for query, con in zip(queries, connections))`. If that's a really long list though you probably would be better off using a threadpool to limit the number of queries running at once to a sensible number.

Comment: However if you had a loop within `get_df1`, the steps in the loop are still executed sequentially, they're just allowed to interleave with the other running coroutines.

Comment: Right now my calls to a postgreSQL DB is increasing (by a lot). I have 6 calls (to three different databases in total) - the Mysql and MSSQL works fine, but two of them are to PostgreSQL and they are insanely slow using async

Comment: How to pass chunksize argument to read_sql function in run_in_executor(None, pd.read_sql, stmt, con) @CutePoison

Comment: `run_in_executor` doesn't support keyword arguments directly, so you need to wrap `read_sql` with `functools.partial`, so something like `loop.run_in_executor(None, partial(pd.read_sql, stmt, con, chunksize=...))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code directly without using the wrapper:

```
await asyncio.to_thread(pd.read_sql, query, con)
```